# How do run the example from asprise ocr code with c++ in my laptop?

Tags: c++, ocr, asprise-ocr-api

i am using the example code to run the asprise library, but when i compile show me an error that i don't understand, please anybody could help me?

I am new using extern library in c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include "asprise_ocr_api.h"

using namespace std;

void testOcr() {
   // CHANGE TO THE ACTUAL PATH to the folder where the aocr.dll or aocr.so locates in
   const char * libFolder = "/home/jesus/Descargas/LIB_FOLDER/libaocr_x64.so";

   // CHANGE TO THE ACTUAL PATH to the input image, can be jpeg, gif, png, tiff or pdf.
   const char * fileImg = "/home/jesus/Descargas/out.tiff";

   LIBRARY_HANDLE libHandle = dynamic_load_aocr_library(libFolder);

   // one time setup
   int setup = c_com_asprise_ocr_setup(false);
   if (setup != 1) {
      cerr << "Failed to setup. code: " << setup << endl;
      return;
   }

   // starts the ocr engine; the pointer must be of long long type
   long long ptrToApi = c_com_asprise_ocr_start("eng", OCR_SPEED_FAST, NULL, NULL, NULL);
   if (ptrToApi == 0) {
      cerr << "Failed to start." << endl;
      return;
   }

   char * s = c_com_asprise_ocr_recognize(ptrToApi, fileImg, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
      OCR_RECOGNIZE_TYPE_ALL, OCR_OUTPUT_FORMAT_PDF,
      "PROP_PDF_OUTPUT_FILE=result.pdf|PROP_PDF_OUTPUT_TEXT_VISIBLE=true|\
      PROP_PDF_OUTPUT_RETURN_TEXT=text", "|", "=");

   cout << "Returned: " << s << endl;

   // do more recognition here ...

   // finally, stops the OCR engine.
   c_com_asprise_ocr_stop(ptrToApi);

   cout << "Unload: " << (dynamic_unload_aocr_library(libHandle) ? "OK" : "Failed") << endl;
}

int main() { // Entry point
   testOcr();
   std::cout << "Press ENTER to exit: ";
   std::cin.ignore();
   return 0;
}
```

The errors are:

```
/tmp/ccqY74eR.o: En la función `dynamic_load_aocr_library(char const*)':
    aspr.cpp:(.text+0x1c5): referencia a `dlopen' sin definir
    aspr.cpp:(.text+0x1db): referencia a `dlerror' sin definir
    aspr.cpp:(.text+0x20f): referencia a `dlsym' sin definir
    aspr.cpp:(.text+0x22c): referencia a `dlsym' sin definir
    aspr.cpp:(.text+0x249): referencia a `dlsym' sin definir
    aspr.cpp:(.text+0x266): referencia a `dlsym' sin definir
    aspr.cpp:(.text+0x283): referencia a `dlsym' sin definir
    /tmp/ccqY74eR.o:aspr.cpp:(.text+0x2a0): más referencias a `dlsym' sin definir a continuación
    /tmp/ccqY74eR.o: En la función `dynamic_unload_aocr_library(void*)':
    aspr.cpp:(.text+0x493): referencia a `dlclose' sin definir
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Please show the command line you are using to compile the code; I think you just need to add `-ldl`.

Comment: hi i am using only g++ aspr.cpp -I path -o asrp

Comment: could you give me a example the how do compile? @KenY-N

Comment: As suggested, append `-ldl`: `g++ aspr.cpp -I path -o asrp -ldl`